# Pass touch events from UIScrollview to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView using custom UICollectionViewCell which in turn contains UIScrollView containing UIImageView.

The UIScrollView has several gesture recognizers attached to it (tap, double tap). I use the UIScrollView in order to zoom into the images.

Problem is the only way I was able to receive the touch events in the UICollectionView was to disable user interaction in the UIScrollView. Despite this the UICollectionView was scrolling, so apparently some of the gestures on the UIScrollView were being passed along to the parent UICollectionView)

I tried another solution by adding these methods in the UIScrollView (custom class)

```
@interface MyScrollView : UIScrollView

@end

@implentation MyScrollView
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [[self nextResponder] touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [[self nextResponder] touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [[self nextResponder] touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [[self nextResponder] touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
@end
```

This helped in allowing the collectionview to receive touches, BUT when swiping up in the scrollview, the collectionview would stop receiving future touches...

What is the proper way to pass the touch event (single/double tap) ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented [gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:)?

See here: [Multiple Gestures for UIGestureRecognizers (iPhone, Cocos2d)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717282/multiple-gestures-for-uigesturerecognizers-iphone-cocos2d)

Comment: Did you Try LongPress Gesture? i think it will help you;

Comment: try if (gesture state=statechanges) as toushes move

Comment: I'm not having problems with the swipe. just with the tapping. the tap gets called in the scroll view but not in the collection view. the swipe gets called in the collection view

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact setup and this is what I did

1. I added a touch gesture to my image view

   ```
   UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(bannerTapped:)];
   singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
   singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
   cell.conversationImageView.tag = indexPath.row;
   [cell.conversationImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
   [cell.conversationImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
   ```
2. Then I added this

   ```
   - (void)bannerTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
       NSLog(@"%@", [gestureRecognizer view]);
       NSLog(@"the tag is %d", [gestureRecognizer view].tag);

       //do something here based on the tag which tells me what row I'm in
   }
   ```

Hope maybe this can work for you

Comment: so in the uicollectionviewcell you add the gesture recognizer? How do you pass the event to the collectionview

Comment: Instead of using - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 to act on the item in the collection view, my banner tapped as shown above now gets called. The key here is the tag which tells me which item I have. 1) My image view is scrollable in the collection view. 2) If I tap on it I can act on it because of the bannerTapped gesture recognizer I added to it when I display it.